# Cannot boot (to try/install) Ubuntu from a USB

Tags: boot, usb

I am having problems to boot my new computer (A Dell Inspiron 16 Plus 7620).  It has 32 GB of RAM and a 1 TB SSD.  I created a USB boot device (22.04.1) some time ago, and then recreated it today.  This USB has worked flawlessly in the past on multiple computers, both to clone HDDs and install Ubuntu.

I get the screen where I can select "Try/install Ubuntu" and then a screen with the Dell logo and the Ubuntu logo underneath with the spinning ("I'm busy at the moment, check back later") graphic.  Then the errors start scrolling wildly.

The ones that show up the most (making it possible to could copy them) are:

1. usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
2. SQUASHFS error:  Unable to read fragment cache entry [4bacc363]
3. SQUASHFS error:  Unable to read page, block 4bacc363, size 612c

Line one shows up twice, followed by one to six copies of lines two and three.

My goal is to use gddrescue to copy the drive, then install Ubuntu (not a dual-boot, just single).

Any sugggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you verify the ISO? It might get corrupted. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu. Also, ensure that the USB drive is verified after flashing the ISO (some apps like Balena Etcher does that).

Comment: The USB drive may have worked flawlessly in the past, but it's displaying hardware errors now. It happens. Time to replace the USB drive.

Comment: I downloaded the ISO again today; I'll try verifying it.  I have another USB, and I'll try that as well.  Thanks!